# Wrong version in pecl install xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, lamp, pecl, php-5.5

I am trying to install xdebug with **pecl install xdebug** on PHP 5.5.27

According to PECL website https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug **latest stable version of xdebug is 2.3.3**

However command above is trying to install **xdebug 2.3.2**

What is wrong with this?

Comment: did you tried my suggestion ?

Comment: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1196

Comment: It looks like that at the time you tried to install the package, it was not yet officially released. I believe that because your question was posted in August and XDebug 2.3.3 was released on 2015-11-09, about 3 months later -- according to the very same [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug) you shared above.

Answer (score 5):

When using `pecl` program to install a package, you can install a specific version, or upgrade to a specific version:

```
pecl install xdebug-2.3.3
```

Even if it's not the case here if one needs to **downgrade** a package, the force (`-f`) option may be required to make it work:

```
pecl install -f xdebug-2.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download it manually:

```
wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.3.3.tgz
tar -xvzf xdebug-2.3.3.tgz
cd xdebug-2.3.3
phpize
./configure
make
```

If you are running a tool like homestead you won't need further steps and do not forget to take backup before steps below.

```
cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php5/20131226
Update /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so
```

Restart the webserver

Comment: I have a script, which compiles php and then automatically compiles necessary extensions. For now I need to have a variable with exact xdebug version to download and I'm trying to get rid of it. My question is related to the PECL repository - what is wrong with it, why it shows one version and installs another.

But anyway thank you for your suggestion maybe it will be useful for somebody.